# How to load data into jqGrid Treegrid

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

My server returns JSON data as follows:

```
{
  "pageIndex": 1,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "pages": 290,
  "total": 2891,
  "nodes": [
    {
      "data": { "id": 1, "name": "Node 1", "leaf": false },
      "errors": []
    },
    {
      "data": { "id": 2, "name": "Node 2", "leaf": true, "parentId": 1 },
      "errors": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to display this in a hierarchical tree structure, so I have configured jqGrid in treegrid mode as follows:

```
$("#tree").jqGrid({
  url: "/tree",
  datatype : "json",
  colModel : [{
    name: "data.id",
    key: true
  }, {
    name: "data.name"
  }],
  colNames : [],
  jsonReader : {
    page : 1,
    records : "total",
    repeatitems : false,
    root : "nodes",
    total : 1
  },
  treeGrid : true,
  treeGridModel : "adjacency",
  tree_root_level : 1,
  ExpandColumn : "data.id",
  ExpandColClick : true,
  treeReader : {
    leaf_field : "leaf",
    parent_id_field : "data.parentId"
  }
});
```

This works fine; however, the column names have to be specified with the `data` prefix. Is there a way to get rid of this prefix for column names without changing the data returned from the server?

Comment: Could you include correct data and the code which you use? You write: "This works fine;", but it can't because of many syntax errors. The data contains syntax error: see missing comma after `"pageSize": 100`. `${"#tree")` instead of `$("#tree")`, missing closing `}` at the end of the code (`});` instead of `}});`), empty array `colNames` instead of using `colNames` and `colModel` of the same length of including no  `colNames`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem then you should fix `colModel`, `jsonReader` and `treeReader` to the following:

```js
colModel : [{
    name: "id",
    key: true
}, {
    name: "name"
}],
jsonReader : {
    cell: "data",
    root : "nodes"
},
treeReader : {
    parent_id_field: "parentId",
    leaf_field : "leaf"
}
```

See the corresponding demo: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ae18ov61/2/. I added additionally the property  `"level": 1` in the item of data, which describes the leaf.